# JSP Content is shown on browser

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am creating a spring boot application. This is just to a Hello World program. When I run the application, the full content of JSP page is shown. Jsp page content is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head><title>Hello world Example</title></head>
 <body>
     <h1>Hello ${name}, How are you?</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

The name variable, I am reading giving it from a controller class HelloWorldController.java .

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView hello() {
  return new ModelAndView("hello").addObject("name", "Nagendra");
 }

}
```

I am new to spring framework and I am not getting what is the problem here. We don't even have web.xml in spring boot application. Can some one help me? I followed http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring/spring-boot-mvc-example to create this sample application.

Comment: What did you type in browser URL?

Comment: @shazin I typed  http://localhost:8080/hello.jsp

Comment: Judging from the tags and namespaces that isn't a JSP but a facelets page...

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: M.Deinum. Ok. Then what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a problem : Edit your JSP to below :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Hello world Example</title></head>
 <body>
     <h1>Hello ${name}, How are you?</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

If this doesn't work, I will tell you changes in Controller side.

*Update*

Use this controller :

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String hello(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("name","Nagendra");
  return "nameofjspwithoutextension"; // if jsp is abc.jsp then return "abc";
 }
```

}

Comment: It is not working. Can you tell me the changes I need to do on Controller side?

Comment: Is it still printing the jsp in browser? Can you please edit your main post and include web.xml and applicationContext.xml as well.

Comment: I created a Spring Starter project in Spring Tool Suite and it didn't generated web.xml or applicationContext.xml . It has added spring boot jars. I followed http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring/spring-boot-mvc-example this link. There it is told like, we can control everything from controller class.

Comment: I have added a controller. Try karlo.